# Spring boot consul - trigger an event on health check failure

Tags: spring, consul, spring-cloud-consul

I have a spring boot consul application. 
I would like that on server fail ober to get an event in my system (like today I have an event whenever a Key Value is changing , an

```
RefreshEvent
```

is throwen  ).

Is there a way to trigger such in event ? 
Are there any thoughts how to by pass it (schedule task which will take all the services and from my client will )